# How do I easily include Google's GCS package into my code?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I want to use the Google Cloud Storage from Java in App Engine. The documentation on how to install this is very thin. I found the source code for com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage but when this source is put into the build path (Eclipse) it generates lots of compile errors. I then track down those sources, add them in and then get more compile errors from more dependencies. It seems like I am missing something about how to use this code in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the library jar and also get its dependencies using [Java Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and the direction mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/tree/master/java) or better yet, use maven and include [appengine-gcs-client](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client/0.6) as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Maven, right-click on your project > Google > Add Google APIs > Cloud Storage JSON API.

This will add all the dependencies that you need. After that, the only jar you need is [appengine-gcs-client](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client/0.6).